# Bootstrap Table Row Formatter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I am working on a bootstrap table for a call log system style application. The application itself works expect for the css. I am using bootstrap with jquery formater to highlight a certain group of call biased on the caller id.

It is currently being displayed as this [image: Current Display]

I would like them to be displayed as this if possible
[image]

I am using javascript with modulus to add the css class to the fields

```
function rowFormatter(item, row) {
    var value = row.CallerId;
     if (value) {
       if (value % 2 === 0) {
          $("#selectItems table tbody").css('background-color', 'grey');
      }
  }
```

}

If the caller id has a modulus of zero it should highlight those rows. This part of css is part of the issue that causing the issue but I have overridden it in the html page

from

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(odd) {background-color: #f9f9f9;}
```

to

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(odd) {background-color: transparent!important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a working fiddle I cannot check if the following works, but it should.

...from what I understand, you have overriden the `background-color` with `!important` so, anything you might be using in your javascript can't override, the `!important` value.

First of all, remove the `!important` from your override OR add this class AFTER your current override is placed.

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr.matchid,
.table-striped > tbody > tr.matchid:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color:grey !important;  // remove !important if you remove your override
}
```

Then replace in your Javascript:

```
function rowFormatter(item, row) {
  var value = row.CallerId;
    if (value) {
      if (value % 2 === 0) {
        $("#selectItems table tbody").addClass('matchid');
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Hi, I cannot create a jsfiddle due to the data being server side, as much as i believe it would help a lot. A hover is not something I need in this case, I sort of need to colour the background baised on the same callerid

Comment: I just named the class `.hovered`, it has nothing to do with `:hover`. Switched it to make it more semantic

Comment: Check and let me know if it works, so I can help you further if needed

Comment: So, did it work? If so, please select the answer as correct.

Comment: No It didn't I kept on trying different attempts to no avail

Comment: Reproduce your code with static content so we can properly help you out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163695/discussion-between-matthias-mccarthy-and-scooterlord).

Answer (score 0):

well,  I believe you should add a class with the styles you need for the odd rows..

I just did an example for you on: https://jsfiddle.net/OsvaldoM/u3mza4L9/
take special care to the following lines:

```
$('.table tr').each(function(value) {
  var $row = $(this);
  if ($row.find('.number').length) {
    if ($row.find('.number').text() % 2 === 0) {
      $(this).addClass('danger');
    }
   }
});
```

Comment: Yes although this is a good answer I cannot overwrite the main css

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of researching and testing. I found a code solution for what I need. Instead of using a formatter, I used a row style and used the following code. This gets me the result that I needed

```
function rowStyle(row, index) {
    if (row.Extension % 2 ==0) {
        return { css: { "background-color": "Gainsboro" } };
    }
    else {
        return { css: { "background-color": "transparent" } };
    }
}
```